# How can I configure single MSP for multiple organizations in configtx.yaml in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying for configuration of multiple organizations with single msp in configtx.yaml. I tried giving same filesystem path for different organizations but no success

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  Using the same MSP for multiple organizations is a very dangerous idea as it means that either organization would be able to masquerade as the other.  Can you add some details on what you actually want to do (and maybe why) as well as post an example of what you have actually tried?

Comment: @GariSing  I understand the risk, but we are trying to do this as multiple organizations (MSP) should be governed by a central organization (its MSP) and not their individual ones. This is what I tried

Giving the same MSP directory while defining multiple organizations 
`&Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp`

Comment: And what was the error?

Comment: @GariSingh Error Endorsing chaincode...